# javascript condition false when values associated with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

```
var dayschoose = $("#days-in-park" + id).val(); // values is 3 
var storageTotalDays = localStorage.getItem("TotalDays"); //value is 12
if (dayschoose > storageParkDays) {
   console.log("if condition");
} else {
   console.log("else conition");
}
```

Here 3 is greater than 12 return false in if conditon but console.log print (" if condition ") dont knwo why

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [`.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) return strings ;)

Comment: can i use parseInt to change string to int

Comment: var storageParkDays = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("ParkAvailDays"));  var dayschoose = parseInt($("#days-in-park" + id).val()); are working fine

Comment: Yes you can - just as @sa289 has shown in his answer or in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `parseInt` - see code below:

```
var dayschoose = parseInt($("#days-in-park" + id).val()); // values is 3 
var storageTotalDays = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("TotalDays")); //value is 12
if (dayschoose > storageParkDays) {
   console.log("if condition");
} else {
   console.log("else conition");
}
```

Comment: If you're using `parseInt`, it's worth [always specifying the radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix), just in case